# Looking for a gui designer without code editing support (not an ide)

Tags: windows, winforms, user-interface, dialog

i'm looking for an open source software that create GUIs , the output for the designed dialogs can be either xml or another format ...
what really important is the editor must not be code specific.
hope there is such an editor, otherwise i will have to modify the Eclipse Visual Editor to satisfy my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is Glade

http://glade.gnome.org/

> By using GtkBuilder, Glade XML files
>   can be used in numerous programming
>   languages including C, C++, C#, Vala,
>   Java, Perl, Python,and others.

Comment: thanks, that was pretty much what i'm looking for :)